# not closing database connection for frequent queries , what will be the impact on performance and memory ?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, singleton

Does it required to close the sqlite database connection always for android application even if its get used frequently in the application. Currently i have single ton class which manages all database queries and cursors open and close. Database connection  is always open never get closed except application taken out from the memory or closed by force. I just do cursor open make query and close it, never close the database connection. I know android caches the database connection objects for later use. So what will be the impact of not closing database connection or do i have to close and open the connection for every query ?

Comment: I haven't discovered any downside to leaving it open for the entire life of an activity.  It also opens/closes fast (even without cache), so haven't figured out much of an upside either.

Comment: @NameSpace my runs continuously with background service and single ton  class will be alive all the time

Comment: Anyone?  I'm thinking of doing the exact same thing.

Comment: @Scott  You can do it. When the app runs it caches the db in memory first then uses it for further queries. But keeping cursor open may cause more memory leak then keep db connection open.